# How to sent data to import Neo4j which is on a remote server?

Tags: neo4j

I have set up neo4j on EC2. Now I can access it using browser. 
I have to import data to neo4j with various size.
For example, at first I will populate it with thousands of nodes and edges, the  later might just add some few nodes and edges to update it.

Obviously, I cannot do these manually every time. 
How can I do these from my client (which is a NodeJs application)?

Comment: Old post but...did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to initialize the database with a large starting graph, you can use one of the two CSV import methods.  Both of these methods will require you to place the CSV files on the local filesystem of the Neo4j server.  The first method lets you submit the import request via a Cypher command and will append data to the current database.  The second method is a stand-alone tool (neo4j-import) that creates a new database from CSV import data.

Details of how to use both can be found here:
https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

Neither of those will help you remotely submit data.  To my knowledge there is no way to do bulk importing without having the data on accessible locally from the Neo4j server.  You could work around that by creating an NFS share accessible by both your Neo4j and application.

The only other option is to build the Cypher commands to create each node/relationship.  That should be sufficient for small loads, but probably won't work well for the large initial load.